# View step by step execution

Tags: c++, backtracking

I have a c++ code which i don't understand that much of it. I'm a c++ beginner and i was wondering if it exist such thing as a program or debugger i don't know that reads through code and interprets it. Ie:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) (let's assume n = 3) the program start and replace
i=0; i<3; i++
i=1; i<3; i++
etc.
```

Basically something that will show me what's happening step by step in the program and how it's using the variables. Thanks
 (i need this in order to understand backtracking).

Answer (score 2):

I thougt [GDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gdb) can do such things.
There should be many tutorials on how to use it.

Or you could use an IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse, they both have step by step debuggers for C++

Comment: most, if not all, debuggers support step by step execution

Comment: Yes of course most debuggers can, but GDB is used by really many people out there and works really great. So I just recommend it because I already used it by myself, and i didn't have any problems. For the beginning I still can recommend IDE's because they have everything already builtin (or it can be added with plugins).